# Directory.GetDirectories order vs Directory.GetFiles order

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core, filesystems

In [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles), there is a remark:

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required.

But in [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories) there is no such remark, so the order of the directories are guaranteed?

And it will be the same in Linux, OSX and Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about latest changes, but earlier this directory method was based on 2 *WinAPI* functions: `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`. And order here is completely **file system dependent**. So order **is not guaranteed**.

In the same OS also you can get different results. It depends from file system. *FAT* and *NTFS* will give different results.

Also this mostly depends from internal order inside file system - so you can't predict order.

Comment: You mean "not guaranteed" between OSs, or even in the same OS?

Comment: In the same OS also. It depends from file system. FAT and NTFS will give different results. Also this mostly depends from internal order inside file system - so you can't predict order. I've investigated this quite deeply some time ago

Comment: Can you add this information to the answer, please?

Comment: Since you said "I'm not sure about latest changes", I will wait for more answers before I mark yours as accepted.

Comment: @baruchiro, Windows itself does not sort the result or make it consistent across file systems. The native syscall is `NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex]`, which has some common setup for the I/O request, but the bulk of the work and behavior is up to the file system's implementation of `IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`. NTFS stores entries in a b-tree that's sorted by name. FAT uses the first available slot in an array, so the order depends on the history of adding and removing entries.